# Add Softether Service

Tags: centos, vpn

I'm running CentOS 7, up-to-date.
I installed Softether like they did in the [tutorial](https://www.softether.org/4-docs/1-manual/7._Installing_SoftEther_VPN_Server/7.3_Install_on_Linux_and_Initial_Configurations).

Now, I tried to add ad service to start ans stop the server. Like in the tutorial. I created the file at /etc/init.d/vpnserver and copied the content. (7.3.8)

```
/sbin/chkconfig --add vpnserver
Dienst vpnserver unterstützt chkconfig nicht
```

[service vpnserver doesn't support chkconfig]

So I don't know how to fix this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you are looking for can be found here:

https://github.com/hsaito/SoftEtherVPN/commit/525348b6d168ced42d8e723033bd2084f6a1eea6

Utilize systemctl not chkconfig.